# How to merge results from two gql queries in to one array of results?

Tags: graphql, typegraphql, graphql-tools

We have two services exposing two sets of schemas, merged in a gateway using [Graphql Tools Schema Stitching](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/tools/docs/schema-stitching/stitch-combining-schemas)

Is it possible to merge queries from two services in such a way that it returns combined results?
Example case:

**Book service** contains data for books

```
interface Searchable {
 id: ID!
} 

type Book implements Searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  # other fields
}

type Query {
 _search( term: String ): [Searchable]
}
```

**User Service** has the data for authors

```
interface Searchable {
 id: ID!
} 

type Author implements Searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  # other fields
}

type Query {
 _search( term: String ): [Searchable]
}
```

**Gateway**

```
interface Searchable {
 id: ID!
} 

type Book implements Searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  # other fields
}


type Author implements Searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  # other fields
}

type Query {
 search( term: String ): [Searchable]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend using [GraphQL-Mesh](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/mesh) - it uses tools under the hood, and enables you to easily merge multiple sources (GraphQL and many others), manipulate it and get one GraphQL endpoint / schema

Comment: Yeah, we are looking into graphql-mesh as a potential rewrite of our gateway. However, I am trying to find out whether It is possible to do so with the basic stitching-merging tools.